# Export to .dae with textures?

Tags: export, collada

Basically I'm trying to export a blender model to .dae, this file has materials with Displacement Map, I did a lot of research on the topic, but I couldn't find a solution, I'm new to Blender, so I was wondering if there is any way to convert this file and bring the texture with it.

Comment: I doubt you can use a displacement map in .dae.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57531/fbx-export-why-there-are-no-materials-or-textures